# Auto calculate sum of the selected radio button

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I've been trying to auto calculate the sums of the selected radio buttons. The values of the radio buttons are from the database. Here is what I've tried so far. It only works on the first modal. Here is a link to a snippet stimulated the data manually.

https://jsfiddle.net/k5zh9m4d/1/

```
<section class="py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="display-4">Menu</h1>
          <?php 
          include "config/dbconfig.php"; 
          $data['productCode'] = "0"; // sample data
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_products");
          //$stmt->bind_param("i", $data['productCode']);
          $stmt->execute();
          foreach ($stmt->get_result() as $i => $stuff) { ?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-6">
                <img src="<?php echo $stuff['image']; ?>" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample milk tea">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                <h3><?php echo $stuff['itemname']; ?></h3>
                <p><?php echo $stuff['itemdescription']; ?></p>
                <hr>
                <h4>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg" disabled>
                  <i class="fa fa-glass fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <?php echo $stuff['itempricethree']; ?>
                  </button>
                </h4>
                <br>
                <hr>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?php echo $stuff['itemcode']; ?>">
                  <i class="fa fa-cart-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  Order
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
        <br><br>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="<?php echo $stuff['itemcode']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><?php echo $stuff['itemname']; ?> - <?php echo $stuff['itempricethree'];?></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <b>Size</b>&nbsp;<small>Pick 1</small>
        <form action="" id="orderform">
        <?php 
          $stmtsize = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_size WHERE productid = '".$stuff['itemcode']."'");
          //$stmt->bind_param("i", $data['productCode']);
          $stmtsize->execute();
          foreach ($stmtsize->get_result() as $i => $forsize) {
              ?>
          <div class="form-check">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
            <?php echo $forsize['size']; ?> - PHP <?php echo $forsize['price']; ?>
            </label>
          </div>
          <?php } ?>
          <p>Total: PHP <span id="total">0</span></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Order now</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
        <?php
}        
?>
     </div>
  </section>   
\\javascript
<script>
$(":radio").on("change", function(){
    var total = 0;
    $(":radio:checked").each(function(){
        total += Number(this.value);
    });
    
    $("#total").text(total);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two `span` elements with the the id of `total`. So the total value of your second modal is displayed in the first modal as this is the first element with an id of `total` in the DOM.

Give your total spans a class instead of an id and search for the closest `form` with regards to the clicked radio button. Then find the total `span` that belongs to it.

Also since there can only be one radio button active at a time there is no need to run through all of them. Simply output the value of the selected radio input.

```js
$(":radio").on("change", function(){
    $(this).closest('form').find('.total').text(Number(this.value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" id="orderform">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <b>Size</b>&nbsp;<small>Pick 1</small>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="rbtn1" value="10.00">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="rbtn1">Regular - PHP 10.00</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="rbtn2" value="20.00">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="rbtn2">Large - PHP 20.00</label>
        </div>
        <p>Total: PHP <span class="total">0</span></p>
    </div>
</form>

<form action="#" id="orderform">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <b>Size</b>&nbsp;<small>Pick 1</small>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="rbtn3" value="30.00">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="rbtn3">Regular - PHP 30.00</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="rbtn4" value="40.00">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="rbtn4">Large - PHP 40.00</label>
        </div>
        <p>Total: PHP <span class="total">0</span></p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I've change the span id to class and now it works but now it appears that when I clicked a radiobutton on the first modal it will add on the second modal.. I've updated my snippet sir.. Thank you so much for your response. https://jsfiddle.net/k5zh9m4d/2/

Comment: See updated answer for a working example. If this answer works for you please mark it as accepted. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to test this code but here's the idea , you can try this.

```
 <input
    onChange="calc(this,<?php $forsize['id']; ?>)"
    class="form-check-input"
    type="radio"
    name="radiobutton"
    id="rbtn2"
    value="10.00">
```

then

```
 <p>Total: PHP <span id="total-<?php echo $forsize['id']; ?>">0</span></p>
```

and

```
<script>
function calc(el, id) {
var value = el.value;
    //do the formula then emit the answer to the span total with id
    
    }
        </script>
```